# Keras Functional API embedding layer output to LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, embedding

When passing the output of my embedding layer to the LSTM layer I'm running into a `ValueError` that I cannot figure out. My model is:

```
def lstm_mod(self, n_cells,batch_size):
        input = tf.keras.Input((self.n_seq, self.n_features))
        embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(batch_size,self.n_seq,input_length=self.n_clusters)(input)
        x= tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n_cells)(embedding) 
        out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
        model = tf.keras.Model(input, out,name="LSTM")
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam')
        return model
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 128, 7, 128]
```

Given that the dimensions passed to the model input and the embedding layer are consistent through the arguments of the model I'm puzzled by this. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keras adds an additional dimension (`None`) when you feed your data through your model because it processes your data in batches.

In this line :

```
input = tf.keras.Input((self.n_seq, self.n_features))
```

You've defined a 2-dimensional input, and Keras adds a 3rd dimension (the batch), hence `expected ndim=3`.

However, the data that is being passed to the input layer is 4-dimensional, which means that your actual input data shape is 3-dimensional + the batch dimension, not 2-dimensional + batch.

To fix this you need to either re-shape your 3-D input to 2-D, or add an additional dimension to the input shape.

Print out the values for `self.n_seq` and  `self.n_features` and find out what is missing from the shape `128, 7, 128` and that should guide you as to what you need to add.

Comment: Thank you! That's very useful. I'm working on implementing your solution